# How to get JSON from server without send JSON request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I need help. 
I use volley for sending json object to my rest API server. And i get data from this API to my app (json). Its work fine:

`JsonObjectRequest mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, JSONDATA, JSONListener, errorListener)
...`

And now I want to send request without `JSONDATA` (i can't set null). It is for global values. There is not necessary send some data. And i dunno how to send this request. Can you help me?

Comment: add your code how you are hitting the service?

Comment: In this case you need to send a GET request and I don't think you will need to pass data - just the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

till i understand ur problem my answer is this

```
StringRequest distRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, YOUR_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
             @Override             public void onResponse(String response) {      
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+response.toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();           

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " "+error.toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        RequestQueue distQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
         distQueue.add(distRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// prepare the Request
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                            // display response     
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());
            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
                Log.d("Error.Response", response);
           }
        }
    );

    // add it to the RequestQueue   
    queue.add(getRequest);
```